# How to select an array element of a promise of a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have that sentence:

```
const tab = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true,});
```

With that sentence, `tab` returns an array of objects with one element:

```
tab:
 Array [ {…} ]
​   0: Object { id: 215, index: 0, windowId: 2602, … }
​   length: 1
​   <prototype>: Array []
```

I can select the first element of the array like this:

```
let tab = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true,});
tab = tab[0]:
```

But I want to select the first element of the array directly, like this:

```
const tab = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true,})[0];
```

Obviously, it isn't works. But I would like some like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the expression in parentheses,

```js
const tab = (await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true}))[0];
```

but a cleaner way would be to use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const [tab] = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true});
```

Comment: Similarly, you could return the first element in `Promise.then()`, and await that.